# Why is my StreamWriter not writing to a .txt file?

Tags: c#, stream

I am try to **write** a file but it is still **empty**...

```
 FileStream f = new FileStream("HighScore.txt", 
                                FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                                FileAccess.ReadWrite);

 StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(f);
 streamWriter.WriteLine("aaaaa");
```

Has anyone encountered this problem and can help me?

Comment: Close/Flush the streams

Comment: Always put your IDisposable instances into a using clause.

Comment: Try streamWriter.Flush() and then streamWriter.Close();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to `Close` the writer; since `StreamWriter` is `IDisposable` let's do it with a `using`:

```
 using(FileStream f = new FileStream("HighScore.txt", 
                                      FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                                      FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
   using(StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(f)) {
     streamWriter.WriteLine("aaaaa");
   }
 }
```

Usually, writers *cache* the updates and apply them on closing. If you want to  apply changes somewhere the *middle of the process*, call `Flush()`. In case you want just to write text to the file you can put it easier

```
File.WriteAllText("HighScore.txt", "aaaaa");
```

Answer (score 2):

StreamWriter is buffering your data. The buffered data is automatically flushed when full or when closing the connection, you're not doing any of it.

Your situation is the data is too small, and thus not flushed.

Closing the connection will solve the problem.

You have few options.

**Manual Flush - Less recommended**

Manually add flush when you want to save the data.

```
steamWriter.Flush()
```

**Closing the connection manually - better, but still not best.**

```
streamWriter.Close();
```

**Disposing the connection - best.**

Wrapping the code with `using` will dispose the resource when the scope `{..}` is finished, the dispose operation will close the connection and thus flush your data.

```
using (var f = new FileStream("HighScore.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(f))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine("aaaaa");
}
```